# How Do I Use A Broadcast Receiver To Send Commands To Objects In A Layout?

Tags: java, android

I am using a service and a broadcast receiver. When the service is started it will put a notification in the user's notification center that returns a START_STICKY. I added an action button to that notification that will stop the service. That part works fine, but I also have a switch object on my activity_main.xml layout that I want it to uncheck when the user taps on that action button to stop the service if the user still has that layout opened, and in focus on their screen at the time they tapped on that action button.

I thought the solution was as easy as using a LayoutInflater, but it's not working for me.

Here is what I tried... I put the following code in the onReceive method in my Broadcast Receiver class. All the other stuff that I have in that method is working fine except for this part in question.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
Switch sw = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
sw.setChecked(false);
```

You would think that would work. I'm telling it to look at a specific layout, and then I told it to execute a uncheck command to the switch object that exists on that layout from the action button in the notification. It's not receiving the command.

Any ideas? I appreciate the help!!

[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UKu6.jpg)

If it helps my project can be downloaded here...
[enter link description here](https://www.filemail.com/d/wgjjjtaxzcuiiqu)

Here are my new changes...

Broadcast Receiver Class

```
public static String ACTION_TURN_OFF_THE_LIGHTS = "com.mathiasapps.lightsonexample.action.TURN_OFF_THE_LIGHTS";


Intent actionStopIntent = new Intent(this, actionTurnOffReceiver.class);
        actionStopIntent.setAction(ACTION_TURN_OFF_THE_LIGHTS);
        PendingIntent actionStopPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, actionStopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

MainActivity Class

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_TURN_OFF_THE_LIGHTS);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

```
    private final MyActivityReceiver receiver = new MyActivityReceiver();

    @SuppressLint("UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialCode")
    public Switch sw;


    class MyActivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            @SuppressLint("UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialCode")
            Switch sw = findViewById(R.id.lights_on_switch);
            sw.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe in activity main put the receiver and uncheck it. I think this won't get the one already running

Comment: It's cool if it can't be done that way. It's just I like to keep my projects as user friendly as possible.

Comment: The user won't see your code. Put another reciever in the activity that is using that xml and have the veiw in a var and switch it off I think that should work. The other activity can fire the intent if it has too

Comment: Ok. So, the onReceive I was talking about in my question should send the command, and the onReceive you mentioned will receive that command in the MainActivity class that should turn off that switch?

Comment: yeah I think so.

Comment: MainActivity that extends AppCompatActivity does not list onReceive in the override methods.

Comment: If I use onCreate to receive the data I get a null pointer exception when I launch the app.

Comment: In the onReceive method from the Broadcast Receiver class I have it sending a string through the Broadcast like this.. context.sendBroadcast(intent, "Stop"); but I'm not sure how the MainActivity.class will receive that string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233299/discussion-between-lllcoderlll-and-solomon-p-byer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is what I tried... I put the following code in the onReceive method in my Broadcast Receiver class. All the other stuff that I have in that method is working fine except for this part in question.

> LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
> Switch sw = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
> sw.setChecked(false);

> You would think that would work.

No, you would not.

> I'm telling it to look at a specific layout, and then I told it to execute a uncheck command to the switch object that exists on that layout from the action button in the notification.

No, you're not.

**Your Problem**

You are inflating a *brand new* instance of your main activity layout, finding the switch within that layout, and setting that switch - which is NOT the switch in your activity - to unchecked.  You are not touching your actual Activity layout by doing this.

**A Solution**

You need to register a broadcast receiver with the Activity so the actual running instance of the Activity can receive the broadcast and toggle the switch that it contains. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers) for an example.

Pseudocode (should go without saying, this is not tested and is meant to guide you towards the solution):

```
class MyActivity {
    // The receiver that will listen for the "off" broadcast
    class MyActivityReceiver : BroadcastReceiver {
        // When this receiver gets notified, call the owning activity's method
        void onReceive(Intent intent) {
            turnOffToggle();
        }
    }

    private final MyActivityReceiver receiver = new MyActivityReceiver();

    protected void onCreate(...) {
        super.onCreate(...)

        // Register the receiver so we get notified while this activity is active
        IntentFilter filter = // create filter for your broadcast intent
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    proteced void onDestroy() {
        // Stop listening once we're killed
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private void turnOffToggle() {
        // Find the switch in THIS active Activity's layout
        Switch sw = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
        sw.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

---

Edit after questions:

1 - when you set up the action you're targeting the service's local receiver with your intent:

```
// Will only invoke `actionTurnOffReceiver` declared in the service.
Intent actionStopIntent = new Intent(this, actionTurnOffReceiver.class);
```

You need a more generic intent any receiver (i.e., the one in the activity) can listen for.

```
// ACTION_TURN_OFF_THE_LIGHTS is some string like "com.my.package.action.TURN_OFF_THE_LIGHTS"
Intent actionStopIntent = new Intent(this, ACTION_TURN_OFF_THE_LIGHTS)
```

2 - Your activity registration is too generic:

```
// This is blindly registering for all broadcasts - or Android will just ignore it
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

As is shown in the example in the documentation I linked to, you have to set up your filter to match the intent you care about. In this case, it's for the "turn off" action:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_TURN_OFF_THE_LIGHTS);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Please review [the entire section on Broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) so you have a better understanding of how they work. And [here's a Medium article](https://medium.com/android-news/broadcast-receivers-for-beginners-a9d7aa03fb76) that goes into Broadcast Receivers.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: I'll just take it that it's not possible.

Comment: It's definitely possible using the pattern I described. "That didn't work" doesn't tell me what you actually did and what your code looks like. Update your question or ask a new one with clear details of what you're trying and what's happening.

Comment: I added a download link of my project to this question.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I didn't realize this is more of a complex issue than what it's worth for my level in programming. It's just too complex for me and I don't get it. I'll just skip this. The rest of the project works as it's meant to.

Comment: I gave it another try. I updated my question. It still doesn't work. How about you download my project from the link in the question that I uploaded earlier, make the corrections, upload the corrected one to a link like I did to send it back for me to download. This is how I learn. I'll use this source as a reference. Otherwise I'll keep spinning my wheels trying to understand and figuring all that out. Thanks!

Comment: And you weren't trying to help me? Look, I appreciate everything you tried doing. It's not your explanations and what you provided for me to read that was insufficient, it's me not understanding what you were explaining, and not comprehending the articles that you provided for me to read. I do apologize. It's not like I didn't try, you can't fault me for not understanding. You need to understand that people learn stuff at different levels. Some people learn by reading, some learn by hands on experience, some learn by visuals and by watching others.

Comment: After really focusing on the reads you sent me and looking at your examples closely, I finally got it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you comments. Glad you figured it out.